# Custom subviews with equal widths in UIStackView

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistackview

I have been trying to achieve a view (PCHorizontalAdjustableView) with 3 custom views (PCSimpleDescriptionView).

The PCSimpleDescriptionView has a vertical UIStackView with 2 labels inside a vertical UIStackView like this:

[image: PCSimpleDescriptionView]

The PCHorizontalAdjustableView which has a horizontal UIStackView for displaying 3 PCSimpleDescriptionViews (colors added to highlight the 3 views).

[image]

The result that I get is this:

[image: Simulator iPhone5S]

What I would ideally like is 3 equally sized PCSimpleDescriptionViews showing the labels in the available space.

The sample project is uploaded [here](https://github.com/arorajatin/TestStackView)

Any idea what should I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is `- (void)setup` method

You add view from xib like a subview 
    `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PCHorizontalAdjustableView" owner:self options:nil];
    [self addSubview:self.view];`

You need add constraints to this new subview or control frame in `- (void)layoutSubviews` method

Add this functions to you custom view's classes (PCHorizontalAdjustableView, PCSimpleDescriptionView) `

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.view.frame = self.bounds;
    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
    [self.view layoutSubviews];
}

- (void)didMoveToWindow {
    [super didMoveToWindow];

    [self setNeedsLayout];
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
}`
```

Fixed code [project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0qjaqlzpn4qs95c/TestStackView-master.zip?dl=0)

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I just added self.view.frame = self.bounds; in layoutSubviews to solve this issue. Other methods were not required it seems.

Comment: But shouldn't the correct frame get set automatically when layout phase happens?

Comment: You must just add constraints after addSubview function. It'll automatic solution.

Comment: What constraints are you talking about? I need to understand why it doesn't happen automatically. You load the nib, then constraint pass should take over -> layout pass -> display pass.

Comment: You load additional view from xib -> add loaded view as subView to your view (from storyboard).

If you want load view from xib - you must mind about container's frame

https://medium.com/@brianclouser/creating-a-custom-view-using-a-xib-in-objective-c-6041140a16ca